# How do I Rspec test a non instance or class method?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a simple script which I'm playing with (a Ruby caesars cypher implementation), none of my methods are written within a Module or Class. How can I write Rspec tests to call these non-instance/class lone type methods?

```
def cypher(string, factor)
  string_array = string.downcase.split('')
  ...
  string_array.each do |item|
    ...
  end
  puts cyphered_array_alpha.join
end
```

Method content omitted for brevity.

Test:

```
describe "#cypher" do
  it "should return characters adjusted by given index" do
    expect(cypher("abcd", 1)).to eql('bcde')
  end
end
```

Ive tried using `{cypher()}` without any joy.

Comment: To meet your test’s expectations, try _returning_ `cyphered_array_alpha.join` instead of just printing it. (`puts` has a return value of `nil`)

Comment: Noted Stefan, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Ruby methods are located in specific modules or classes

When you define method on top level you define this method in `Object` as private method. Therefore it is available in any object. Usually it is a bad idea

Probably it's better to use some container for your method (class or module) and test this class or module

Also it's better to define method without any output — just return some value. In this case you can use this method anywhere, not only in STDOUT (for example in the web app, telegram bots, etc.)

```rb
# lib/caesar_cypher.rb

module CaesarCypher
  module_function

  def encrypt(string, factor)
  end

  def decrypt(cypher, key)
  end  
end
```

And then

```rb
# spec/caesar_cypher_spec.rb

describe CaesarCypher do
  describe '.encrypt' do
    it 'encrypts string...' do
      expect(described_class.encrypt('abcd', 1)).to eq('bcde')
    end
  end

  describe '.decrypt' do
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I've learned – from [this](https://www.rubypigeon.com/posts/rspec-expectations-cheat-sheet/) helpful RSpec cheatsheet, that there are some less commonly used, more 'advanced' RSpec matchers, one of which; `output(...).to_stdout` can be used to evaluate block output. Though not a full explanation of how to test non-instance or class methods (aka a singleton method perhaps?), this matcher worked in my case:

```
expect {cypher("abcd", 1)}.to output("zabc\n").to_stdout
```

Comment: Note that this tests the method’s output rather than its return value. (your example says “it should return …”)